# Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Let $w$ be the product of all the elements in $G$. Prove that $w^2 = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Let $w$ be the product of all the elements in $G$. Prove that $w^2 = 1$.

**Where I Am:**

Well, I know that the commutator subgroup of $G$, call it $G'$, is simply the identity element, i.e. $1$. But, can I conclude from this that $\forall g \in G, g=g^{-1}$, i.e., $\forall g \in G, g^2 = gg^{-1} = 1$, which is our desired result? That just seems... strange. But, it kind of makes sense. After all, each element in $G$ has an associated inverse element (because it's a group), and because it's abelian, we can always position an element next to its inverse, i.e.

$$ w^2 = (g_1g_1^{-1}g_2g_2^{-1}g_3g_3^{-1}\cdot \cdot \cdot g_ng_n^{-1})^2 = (1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot \cdot \cdot 1)^2=1.$$

Is that all there is to it? Actually, looking at it now, I don't even need to mention the commutator subgroup, do I...

Comment: Nope.  No need for the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Hint: elements of order 2 can't be paired off with the inverse (because it's the very same element), so they need to be treated separately.

Comment: @A.S. I'm sorry, this is a really dumb question, but which elements are of order 2? Isn't the "order" the amount of elements? (Not too familiar with group theory over here.)

Comment: Order of the element $a$ is the smallest $n\geq 1$, s.t. $a^n=1$.

Comment: @A.S. But the smallest $n$ s.t. $a^n = 1$ is always just $0$, is it not? EDIT: just saw your edit.

Comment: The order of $a$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ with $a^{n} = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following "proof" that $w = 1$. See if you can patch it up to reach to conclusion that $w^{2} = 1$ instead.

We partition the non-identity elements of $G$ into two sets, which we call $S = \{g_{1}, g_{2}, \dots\}$ and $S' = \{g_{1}^{-1}, g_{2}^{-1}, \dots\}$.
We do this by iteratively building up the two sets. We start with each set empty, and at each step pick an element $g$ from those not in either of $S$ or $S'$. We put $g$ in $S$, and $g^{-1}$ in $S'$.

Then we can write out the product $w$ in a convenient way.
\begin{equation*}
w = \prod_{g \in G}g = 1 \cdot \left(\prod_{i}g_{i}\right) \left(\prod_{i}g_{i}^{-1}\right) = \prod_{i}g_{i}g_{i}^{-1} = \prod_{i}1 = 1
\end{equation*}
Note that we used that $G$ is abelian going from $(\prod g_{i})(\prod g_{i}^{-1})$ to $\prod g_{i}g_{i}^{-1}$. Thus we get $w = 1$.

Hint: Are $S$ and $S'$ disjoint?

Comment: First off, $S$ and $S'$ are not necessarily disjoint because it is possible that for some $g_i$'s, $g_i=g_i^{-1}$, right?

Comment: I assume that the problem is the fact that there wouldn't necessarily be the same amount of $g_i$'s, and thus you couldn't combine their products. I mean, each element has a unique inverse: either itself, or some other element. So, you can't partition $G$ into just elements and their inverses because it would "double count" those elements that are their own inverses. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why squaring it would help, though...

Comment: You can separate the elements into those who equal their own inverse and those that don't.  The final product will be the product of those that do, and it will either be the identity or a single element that is equal to it's own inverse.  If you multiply that element by another element that is it's own inverse, you'll get a third element that is its own inverse.  I think associativity or induction might show this is impossible but I'm not certain.

Comment: Of course the product of two elements of order two is of order 2!  if $h^2 = 1$ and $j^2 = 1$ then $(hj)^2 = hjhj = hhjj = 1$.

w = the product of all elements that are order 2 which does *NOT* equal 1.  *but* the product of all elements of order 2 is of order 2, so $w^2 = 1$.

Comment: You are right that the elements $g$ with $g = g^{-1}$ are the problem. They are the only ones that do not cancel. Then $w$ is a product of elements that are their own inverses. What does this tell us about $w^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be finite group and let $I =\{g \in G \mid g^2 = 1 \}$. For notational purposes, write $I = \{ i_{1}, i_{2}, \dots, i_{k} \}$ and $G \setminus I = \{g_{1}, g_{2}, \dots , g_{l} \}$ Then since $G$ is abelian we have that
$$
w^2  = \left( \prod_{i \in I} i^2 \right) \left( \prod_{g \in G \setminus I} g^2 \right)=  [i_{1}^2i_{2}^2 \ldots i_{k}^2][g_{1}^2g_{2}^2 \ldots g_{l}^2].
$$
Now, since $i_{j}^2 = 1$ for all $i_{j} \in I$ by definition, the left product is simply equal to $\text{id}_{G}$. For the second product, since each $g_{i} \in G \setminus I$ is not self inverse by definition and $G$ is abelian, we may pair up each element with its inverse to give the identity. Hence we have that $w^2 = 1$.

Comment: Why does this not have upvotes, its a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

$w = g_1...g_r$, where $g_1,..., g_r$ are the elements of $G$ of order $2$ (all other elements can be paired with their inverses, or in the case of $e$, can be removed), then $w^2= g_1^2...g_r^2= e^r = e$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Corollary :(1) The product of all the elements of G is the product of the elements that are their own inverses. (2) Hence by (1) ,if $ p$ is prime then  $(p-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your argument is essentially the way to go and the derived subgroup is indeed irrelevant. To make the proof more formal, you can do as follows.

The map $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is bijective on $G$. Writing $G=\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\}$ and
$$
w=g_1g_2\dots g_n
$$
we have
$$
w^{-1}=(g_1g_2\dots g_n)^{-1}=\color{red}{g_n^{-1}\dots g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}}
=g_1g_2\dots g_n=w
$$
because the term painted red is again the list of all elements of $G$, just possibly in a different order, but commutativity of multiplication allows to reorder them.

Answer (score 0):

List the elements of G as {$g_1, ...., g_n$} for each $g_i$ there is precisely one element $g_i^{-1}$ so that $g_i^{-1}g_i = 1$.  It is possible that $g_i = g_i^{-1}$ or it is possible $g_i^{-1} = g_j$ for some other j.  It doesn't matter.

The set of all inverses {$g_1^{-1}.... g_n^{-1}$} is the same set as {$g_1, ...., g_n$} as each inverse is also in the G and there is a 1-1 correspondence between elements and their specific inverses.

As G is abelian $w^2$ = $\prod g_i$ x $\prod g_1^{-1}$ = $\prod (g_i^{-1}*g_i) = \prod 1 = 1$.